# Existence of an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

> Does there exist a function $f(z)$ that is analytic in the unit disk $D$ and satisfies $$f\left( \frac{1}{n} \right) =f\left(\frac{-1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n^5}$$ for $n=2, 3, 4, \ldots$?

My hunch is that there is not. My take would be to assume the contrary, and then to attempt to build the power series around $z=0,$ with the idea of that power series ending up being equivalently zero, a contradiction. I can show using continuity that $f(0)=0$ and using Cauchy-Riemann that $f'(0)=0$. But I can't get any further - and I am not even sure this is the correct approach (the fact that I'm not using the specific power of $n$ given in the problem is troublesome).

Thank you so much once again!

Answer (score 1):

Use the theorem that two analytic functions defined on a connected open set $D$, which agree on a set having an accumulation point in $D$, must be identical.

Since $f(1/n) = 1/n^5$, the function $f(z)$ must be $z^5$. But this doesn't agree with the other condition.

The idea you mentioned of examining the power series at 0 is in fact related to the proof of that theorem, and you can avoid use of the theorem by using that idea.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Of course the answer follows straight away from that. Supposing I wanted to go down the rabbit trail of recovering the power series, would eventually getting a nonzero constant sixth derivative at zero (and zero thereafter) be too messy of a formula given the information in the problem, or is there something I'm forgetting?

Comment: Well, you can show that if $a_n \to 0$, then the first nonzero term of a power series $f(z)$ centred at $0$ is entirely determined by the values $f(a_n)$. Then subtract that term, and continue by induction. This will show that only one power series is possible at $0$. By (one) definition of an analytic function, that power series must be a representation of your function in a neighbourhood of $0$, and you must have many terms $-1/n$ in it.